# How do I save my rendered animation as a video/gif?

Tags: rendering, animation, export

Blender is only giving me the option to save as an image, it took a long time to render, so I hope to god I don't have to do it again, but if I do, so be it. I tried looking it up and found nothing.

This is a picture of what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a series of images has been rendered, you will find them in the folder where Blender saves its renders, which is `C:\tmp` by default (check the path under 'Output' in the Output Properties tab, shown below, to check what your current output folder is).
It *could* be you only rendered frame 120, as that's the current frame showing in your Render Result: maybe you hit 'Play' to check your animation, and started rendering using <kbd>F12</kbd> (Render Image) once the animation got to frame 120.

If you go the Output Properties window in Blender, you'll find options, under 'Output', to save as file formats other than .PNG, such as .JPEG, .BMP, or video formats such as .AVI and .MPEG:

[image]

Be sure to set the 'Frame Start' and 'End' to the sequence of frames that contain your animation.
Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> to render an animation.

Just like you can convert the series of images it might have created into a video file, you can convert it to a .GIF file afterwards.

Comment: The fact that the _Image Editor_ shows frame 120 doesn't mean that she only rendered frame 120, because it always shows the last rendered image. Instead, unless she already was on frame 120 when starting to render, the number is a good indication that she might have rendered the complete sequence. My answer came a little later than yours (I'm just too slow for BSE  :D ), if there is anything worth adding to yours, take it... I might delete mine afterwards.